# Using the Rotation Interpolator about other Axes

Tags: rotation, java-3d

How can I make a Rotation Interpolator that rotates about the y or z axis? I've so far only managed to get it to work about the x-axis, which seems to be the default.

```
RotationInterpolator interpolator = new RotationInterpolator(rotationAlpha, tg, new Transform3D(), 0.0f, (float)(Math.PI/2.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the Javadoc of the class RotationInterpolator?

```
/**
 * @deprecated As of Java 3D version 1.3, replaced by
 * <code>TransformInterpolator.setTransformAxis(Transform3D)</code>
 */
 public void setAxisOfRotation(Transform3D axisOfRotation) {
    setTransformAxis(axisOfRotation);
}
```